# What is 'move it along'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence

One of the colleague has mentioned the following,

We should be able to do it, but **to move it along (My name)**, please do it at xyz.

What should I infer from this statement?

Comment: That "we" are not able to do it right now, but xyz will result in it getting done quicker.

Comment: Note that there should be a comma before “(My name)”: your name is being used as a vocative here, not as the object of the preposition _along_. In other words: “Zeus, please do XYZ in order to move it along”; not “Please do XYZ in order to move it along Zeus”. Nothing is being moved along you, if that was how you had been reading it.

Answer (score 3):

To "Move it [something] along," is business parlance for completing some actions on a project to show that it is not being forgotten about.

In this instance it sounds like you cannot complete the project but rather than letting it sit idle, you should do 'xyz' to show the client that you have not forgotten about it and that things are progressing.

Comment: +1. But I think the meaning of `at XYZ` is unclear.

Comment: +1 But it is not only used in circumstances involving a client. And one doesn't only 'move it along' in order to demonstrate that things are happening. Take an instance where management are not clear how they will be able to complete a project due to complications. Someone might say *Despite that I think we should start to move it along so that we don't lose time*.

Answer (score 2):

"*to move it along*" is to enhance or further the projects' development, demonstrating progress.

Answer (score 1):

"Move it along" here means "bring it to completion."  Your colleague means that the team ("we") has the capacity to do the project, but to actually get that project on its way to completion you must do the work it will take at xyz.

Comment: It does not mean to bring it to completion. It means to make progress (towards completion)

Comment: on its way (to completion) is spot-on, though ... imho.